# Magento : controller_action_predispatch is not working

Tags: magento

I am trying to create controller_action_predispatch event:

This is my Mbyte/Pushnotification/etc/config.xml file code

```
   <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_mbyte_pushnotification_index_index>
               <observers>
                    <Mbyte_Pushnotification>

                        <class>Mbyte_Pushnotification/Observer</class>
                        <method>indexPreDispatch</method>
                    </Mbyte_Pushnotification>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_mbyte_pushnotification_index_index>
    </events>
```

My controller code : Mbyte/Pushnotification/controllers/IndexController.php file code

```
class Mbyte_Pushnotification_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
     Mage::log('Run',null,'log.log');

    }
    }
```

Observer file code:

```
class Mbyte_Pushnotification_Model_Observer {
              public function indexPreDispatch($observer)
               {    
                 Mage::log('Check',null,'observer.log');

                      }}
```

controller_action_predispatch is not working.
Is there something i am doing wrong?

Comment: it will not correct your bug, but cast your $observer like `public function indexPreDispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)`

Comment: I tried this but didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

The event triggered should be

`controller_action_predispatch_pushnotification_index_index` 
instead of 
`controller_action_predispatch_mbyte_pushnotification_index_index`

in case you did not modify the frontend name ("pushnotification") of your controller.

Therefore you have to update your config.xml to

```
<events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_pushnotification_index_index>
           <observers>
                <Mbyte_Pushnotification>
                    <class>Mbyte_Pushnotification_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>indexPreDispatch</method>
                </Mbyte_Pushnotification>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_pushnotification_index_index>
</events>
```

you could also write

```
<events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_pushnotification_index_index>
           <observers>
                <Mbyte_Pushnotification>
                    <class>pushnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>indexPreDispatch</method>
                </Mbyte_Pushnotification>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_pushnotification_index_index>
</events>
```

if you named your module "pushnotification", which i assume.

Answer (score 0):

According to magento define event depends should be

```
controller_action_predispatch_frontName_Controller_Youaction
```

it is define like:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName(),
        array('controller_action' => $this));
```

Comment: I tried this but this didn't work for me. Could you explain with example.